# Give samba server a network name

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, dns, samba

I have samba server running on ubuntu 10.04 lts. At the moment I am connecting to it from windows 7 by typing \\192.168.1.3\sharename. Is there a way to give the ip a "name". At my school I can type in \hsmain\sharename. How would I set something like this up?

Comment: if you are the only client to that server, you can add an entry in your hosts file located at c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DNS server (like bind) or something substituting it in your network. You can install dnsmask for example on your ubuntu server or if your network is simple, you can use hosts files on all machines.